# Attempting to flatten nested objects based on a specific field key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Am looking to map through an array, take the key/value of a specified field, then merge it into the main object.

Currently my array looks like:

```
const data = [
   {
      "id": "3QXNO4SDo08FgAfQy3z5",
      "title": "Team One",
      "scores": [
         {
            "id": "DbkZljn22YSGVBLxiT4o",
            "score": 88
         },
         {
            "id": "v7ss2ypT4qf9RIvIynJp"
            "score": 5,
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id": "EmoL3dlPWpOPPiLixIYJ",
      "title": "Team Two",
      "scores": [
         {
            "id": "DbkZljn22YSGVBLxiT4o",
            "score": 77,
         },
         {
            "id": "v7ss2ypT4qf9RIvIynJp",
            "score": 0,
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

And I need to simplify it down to:

```
[
   {
      "id": "3QXNO4SDo08FgAfQy3z5",
      "title": "Team One",
      "DbkZljn22YSGVBLxiT4o": 88,
      "v7ss2ypT4qf9RIvIynJp": 5,
   },
   {
      "id": "EmoL3dlPWpOPPiLixIYJ",
      "title": "Team Two",
      "DbkZljn22YSGVBLxiT4o": 77,
      "v7ss2ypT4qf9RIvIynJp": 0,
   }
]
```

Taking the unique ID of the score and using it as my object key.

I imagine this requires nested looping to get the result. I would post my coding attempts, but they were seriously flawed and confusing.

Comment: That's a strange object. Are you sure that is what you want to do?

Comment: Can answers use features added to ECMAScript introduced after 2015? Currently your tags indicate otherwise (limiting them to ES6 and ES5).

Comment: Matt - it's purely for display purposes and sorting in a dynamic table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `Array#map` and `Array#reduce` to achieve the desired output.

```js
const mapped = data.map(({ scores, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  ...scores.reduce((output, score) => ({ ...output, [score.id]: score.score }), {})
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

your questiopn is not clear ..
but this answer may help you

```
const data= [
   {
      "id": "3QXNO4SDo08FgAfQy3z5",
      "title": "Team One",
      "scores": [
         {
            "id": "DbkZljn22YSGVBLxiT4o",
            "score": 88
         },
         {
            "id": "v7ss2ypT4qf9RIvIynJp"
            "score": 5,
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id": "EmoL3dlPWpOPPiLixIYJ",
      "title": "Team Two",
      "scores": [
         {
            "id": "DbkZljn22YSGVBLxiT4o",
            "score": 77,
         },
         {
            "id": "v7ss2ypT4qf9RIvIynJp",
            "score": 0,
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

by click on data field:

```
const array = [];

function handleSelect(id) {

const copyData = [...data];
const foundItems =  copyData.map(item => item.id === id);

array.push(foundItems)

}
```

finally array is:

```
const array = [
   {
      "id": "3QXNO4SDo08FgAfQy3z5",
      "title": "Team One",
      "DbkZljn22YSGVBLxiT4o": 88,
      "v7ss2ypT4qf9RIvIynJp": 5,
   },
   {
      "id": "EmoL3dlPWpOPPiLixIYJ",
      "title": "Team Two",
      "DbkZljn22YSGVBLxiT4o": 77,
      "v7ss2ypT4qf9RIvIynJp": 0,
   }
]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm unsure where I should call the handleSelect function. I'm looking for a solution that will restructure the entire array at once.

Answer (score -2):

```
const flattenedArray = data.map((dt) => {
  let ar = [];
  dt.scores.forEach((n, i) => (ar = { ...ar, [n.id]: n.score }));
  return { ...dt, ...ar };
});
```

Returns the desired flattened array.